# SQL Server Database freespace for all servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Hi I am looking for a way to get a list of freespace on database files from all servers.

Every method I have come across returns only the info for the connected database.
Is there a method to retrieve data for db's on all servers?

I have found a way to get sizes of mdf and ldf files but now I need freespace.

Thanks all.

Comment: @MartinK. Joel is correct. Even if I could view it in a window I wouldn't as I need this info for an automated report I am building.

Comment: I'm not really a fan, so I hesitate to list this as an answer, but if all else fails there's `sp_msforeachdb`

Comment: SELECT DB_NAME() AS DBNAME,

NAME AS FILENAME,

SIZE/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(NAME, 'SPACEUSED') AS INT)/128.0 AS FREESPACEMB

FROM SYS.MASTER_FILES

WHERE DATABASE_ID = DB_ID()

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks for the tip, I find sp_msforeachdb to be tedious!

Comment: @mohan111 That is only for the connected database... I need for all databases. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
create table #space (dbname varchar(50), filename varchar(50), size int, used int, freespace int)

DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'USE ? insert #space Select db_name(), name, size,  fileproperty(name, ''SpaceUsed'') as Used, size - fileproperty(name, ''SpaceUsed'') as FreeSpace From dbo.sysfiles' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command 

select * from #space

drop table #space
```

Comment: I've come across a query with the same results, but Is there a way to have all that listed in a single table?

Comment: is "used" column supposed to be "free"? There is "used" and "spaceused" which equal size.